# Data Pipeline dump for DynamoDb to S3 failed all the time

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dump, amazon-data-pipeline

I used instruction to setup dumps for DynamoDb: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part2.html

Data Pipeline setup was fine. But after execution task I have same error all the time. I researched this error, but can't find things/hint that will help me. Is there someone who had same error or any ideas why it is possible and how to fix?
Error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Moved Permanently (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: 301 Moved Permanently; Request ID: 46B92304962E5633), S3 Extended Request ID: z8rZwvvo+jxU868kq8hy1AHbRso+WbOiwCEbfvn4EGZKYDarK8s/+6sbCDOp39tF625KU26v7YE= at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182) at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489) at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310) at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3796) at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1060) at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1035) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:199) at sun.reflect.Na
errorStackTrace
amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: Failed to complete EMR transform. at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.EmrActivity.runActivity(EmrActivity.java:67) at amazonaws.datapipeline.objects.AbstractActivity.run(AbstractActivity.java:16) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeRemoteRunner(TaskPoller.java:136) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeTask(TaskPoller.java:105) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller$1.run(TaskPoller.java:81) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.executeWork(PollWorker.java:76) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.run(PollWorker.java:53) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Moved Permanently (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: 301 Moved Permanently; Request ID: 46B92304962E5633), S3 Extended Request ID: z8rZwvvo+jxU868kq8hy1AHbRso+WbOiwCEbfvn4EGZKYDarK8s/+6sbCDOp39tF625KU26v7YE= at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182) at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489) at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310) at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3796) at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1060) at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1035) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:199) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:190) at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:103) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:743) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1402) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.exists(EmrFileSystem.java:317) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:131) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:460) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:343) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at amazonaws.datapipeline.cluster.EmrUtil.runSteps(EmrUtil.java:286) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.EmrActivity.runActivity(EmrActivity.java:63) ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer.
By unknown reason EMR doesn't want to write to my specific bucket on S3. 
But when I created new one bucket - dump was created successfully.

So, if you have same error in future, just try with another S3 bucket.